# How do I get JAVA_HOME to show me? It only shows it to me if I do source ~ / .bash_profile first

Tags: java, terminal

Good, when trying to do: *echo $ JAVA_HOME*, it only shows me the path if I first put *source ~ / .bash_profile*. How could I solve this?

XXXXXXXXX@MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME

XXXXXXXXXX@MacBook-Pro ~ % source ~/.bash_profile
XXXXXXXXXz@MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Normally your `.bash_profile` would be sourced automatically. Maybe you're not using bash. Try `echo $SHELL`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/866683/iterm-zsh-not-reading-bashrc-or-bash-profile

Comment: If I do *echo $shell*
xxxxx@MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

I'm using zsh, and how can I configure it here?

Comment: The problem was that MacOS now use Zsh not bash, and you have to do a simple thing:

Comment: cat ~/.bash_profile >> ~/.zshrc  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using, you must make the modifications in the `~/.zshrc` file. Please add the following entry in the `~/.zshrc`file, if this file is not there, please create one.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

alternatively, you can source the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file from the `~/.zshrc` file
by creating the following entry,`source ~/.bashrc` in the `~/.zshrc` file

```
echo `source ~/.bashrc` >> ~/.zshrc
```

once you are done, either source `~/.zshrc` file or restart the session.
I hope it would solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I execute * cat ~/.bash_profile >> ~/.zshrc   * and all runs correctly

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps given below to set up `JAVA_HOME`:

```
$ cd ~
$ vi .bash_profile
```

Put the following line into .bash_profile file, save and exit

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Now, read and execute the content of `.bash_profile file` once

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

You are not required to use the command, `source .bash_profile` anymore. Now, you can check `JAVA_HOME` from any directory in your system.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```